# Get the COUNT() in row specific case (the counts will depend on the column)

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get the count of rows, but ‘counts’ is a specific case.

### TABLE A

```
   id   |  category  |         time
=============================================
      1 |          1 |  2015-02-09 12:00:00
      2 |          3 |  2015-02-09 13:00:00
      3 |          2 |  2015-02-09 14:00:00
      4 |          3 |  2015-02-09 14:00:00
      5 |          3 |  2015-02-09 15:00:00
      6 |          1 |  2015-02-09 16:00:00
      7 |          1 |  2015-02-09 16:00:00
      8 |          1 |  2015-02-09 17:00:00
```

---

**'counts' is the same 'category' total counts.**

**'order' is ordinal number of 'counts' ORDER BY ASC**

'order' meaning is like below.

```
 order | counts | id | category |         time
========================================================
     1 |      4 |  1 |        1 |  2015-02-09 12:00:00
     2 |      4 |  6 |        1 |  2015-02-09 16:00:00
     3 |      4 |  7 |        1 |  2015-02-09 16:00:00
     4 |      4 |  8 |        1 |  2015-02-09 17:00:00

     1 |      1 |  3 |        2 |  2015-02-09 14:00:00

     1 |      3 |  2 |        3 |  2015-02-09 13:00:00
     2 |      3 |  4 |        3 |  2015-02-09 14:00:00
     3 |      3 |  5 |        3 |  2015-02-09 15:00:00
```

---

How can I write a query to get the results below? (Add two columns)

### Results

```
 order | counts | id | category |         time
========================================================
     1 |      4 |  1 |        1 |  2015-02-09 12:00:00
     1 |      3 |  2 |        3 |  2015-02-09 13:00:00
     1 |      1 |  3 |        2 |  2015-02-09 14:00:00
     2 |      3 |  4 |        3 |  2015-02-09 14:00:00
     3 |      3 |  5 |        3 |  2015-02-09 15:00:00
     2 |      4 |  6 |        1 |  2015-02-09 16:00:00
     3 |      4 |  7 |        1 |  2015-02-09 16:00:00
     4 |      4 |  8 |        1 |  2015-02-09 17:00:00
```

---

Comment: How do you build `order` exactly?

Comment: What exactly you want as output? Explain your question in detail. @Salmon

Comment: @juergend I added the supplementary description, thank you :)

Comment: That would be a `CROSS APPLY` in Sql Server, not sure if something similar exists in MySQL

Comment: @GhanshyamKatriya, I added the description, thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following

```
Select id,category,(select count(*) from catt as ct where ct.category = catt.category)as counts from catt
```

Working [**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3ced9/1/0)

**As per 2nd requirement ->**

```
set @category := '', @num := 1;


Select id,category,(select count(*) from catt as ct where ct.category = 

catt.category)as counts,@num := if(@category = catt.category, @num + 1, 1) as 

row_number , @category := category as dummy from catt order by category DESC
```

Working **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3ced9/4/1)**

Comment: @Salmon , I included woring sqlFiddle.

Comment: Thank you, but I need the 'order'. (could see above description)

Comment: @Salmon , yes doing it.

Comment: Cool, but what is the 'DUMMY' in your result :P

Comment: @Salmon  Check  Updated query it returns result

Comment: You dont need to deal with Dummy column , its for processing Order field OK ? And i used `row_number` For `orders` as column name , you can rename it.

Comment: @Salmon Thanks , you may contact me for any queries.Glad to help you!